# storing python list into mysql and accessing it

Tags: python, mysql

How can I store python 'list' values into MySQL and access it later from the same database like a normal list?

I tried storing the list as a `varchar` type and it did store it. However, while accessing the data from MySQL I couldn't access the same stored value as a list, but it instead it acts as a string. So, accessing the list with index was no longer possible. Is it perhaps easier to store some data in the form of sets datatype? I see the MySQL datatype 'set' but i'm unable to use it from python. When I try to store set from python into MySQL, it throws the following error: `'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_set_to_mysql'.` Any help is appreciated

P.S. I have to store co-ordinate of an image within the list along with the image number. So, it is going to be in the form [1,157,421]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a serialization library like `json`:

```
import json

l1 = [1,157,421]
s = json.dumps(l1)
l2 = json.loads(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an ORM like SQLAlchemy?

Anyway, to answer your question directly, you can use `json` or `pickle` to convert your list to a string and store that. Then to get it back, you can parse it (as JSON or a pickle) and get the list back.

However, if your list is always a 3 point coordinate, I'd recommend making separate `x`, `y`, and `z` columns in your table. You could easily write functions to store a list in the correct columns and convert the columns to a list, if you need that.

Comment: Thanks mate, json worked like a charm. Actually, I have a number of images for a single user and a pointer to the image for every image is stored in my list along with the image co-ordinates, so separate column for each was out of question. Anyway, json worked, so thanks!